# In the movie Krull, what happened in the Spider Den?

Tags: krull

At the middle of this spider cavern is a cocoon like house with a woman in it. She seems to have power over the guardian-a giant white/plastic spider. After getting the needed information, she turns over an hourglass, the old man escapes while the guardian is frozen in time. Afterward, the old man dies, and the big spider jumps on the cocoon, and you hear the lady scream.

What happened to the old man to make him die and the lady?

Comment: First *Krull* question!

Comment: I know right! I saw it as a kid in like 89/90, I didn't think it was a bad movie at all.

Comment: My brother mocks me for liking Krull, and it does have some problems (especially the final battle with the Beast), but I think it's a pretty good fantasy movie overall.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

She doesn't turn the hourglass over.  She breaks the hourglass, and gives the old man the sand, so that he can get back to the group with the information of where the fortress will rise next (it both keeps him alive and gets him past the spider).  With the hourglass broken, she has no further control over the guardian, and it eats her.  When the old man runs out of sand, he dies as well, after passing the information on.  The fact that his remaining life would be tied to the sands is the price he pays for the widow to tell him what he needs to know.

It looks like the sands are some sort of an artifact that controls the spider, but once you begin to use them, your life is tied to them.  The widow had survived this long by having them in the hourglass, but once they're outside of it, they are expended when they fall?  It's not well-explained.  Basically, Krull is really big on having heroes have to die every step of the way.